# Can someone explain why the output is 513?

Tags: c, pointers, binary, char, printf

The output is `513` for this code involving pointers in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *x;
    int a;
    x = (char *) &a;

    a = 512;
    x[0] = 1;
    x[1] = 2; 

    printf("%d\n",a); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please type the code and error(s). Code in a photo does not follow Stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: [Don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your question to show us the code and output copy-pasted as *text*.

Comment: Regarding your problem, try "drawing" the integer `a` on paper. Use one square per byte. Fill in the values you set through `x`. Convert the bytes to binary. Connect all the binary values from the bytes into one single value. Convert back to decimal. What is its value?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to learn from this example. The line `a = 512;` does not matter much, because the following 2 lines overwrite the value byte by byte.

Comment: @Cheatah: The line `a = 512;` is important, because the following 2 lines only partially overwrite the bytes of `a`, assuming that a platform is being used on which `sizeof(int)` is larger than `2`. If it weren't for this line, then `x[2]` and `x[3]` would have unspecified values.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in the used system less significant bytes precede most significant byte in the internal representation of objects of the type `int`.

So after these statements

```
x[0] = 1;
c[1] = 2;
```

the internal binary representation of the variable `a` looks like

```
00000000 00000000 00000010 00000001
                  |   2  | |   1  |
```

that is equivalent to the value `512 + 1 = 513`.